# Deriving grid of points from gridded vector dataset using R?

Tags: r, vector-grid

I have a large gridded vector dataset (see extract below) and would like to derive a grid of points centered in each cell of the grid. Is there a way to do this in R?

[image: extract]

Comment: In R look at sp::spsample with the regular option.

Comment: That’s what I was looking for — thank you Jeffrey!

Comment: There are some functions for independent sampling of the polygons in the spatialEco package as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dataset seems to be based on a given square/grid. I assume you can prepare a point layer (on the full extent of your dataset) based on the same logic + a given x/y offset to center these points in your squares. Then an intersection query will generate the awaited points.

Answer (score 0):

Based on JeffreyEvans's reply, I would suggest using:
`sp::spsample`

Documentation: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sp/versions/1.2-7/topics/spsample